# Plus equals operator to increase value each time

Tags: javascript

I am sure this is very simple but I can't get seem to get this to work just right.  Here is my code:

```
var zero = 10;

function some(elem, num) {
    return elem += num;
}

console.log(some(zero, 10));
console.log(some(zero, 10));
console.log(some(zero, 10));
```

From what I understand, I was expecting the variable in `zero` to increase each time by 10..  So, it would be 10, 20 and 30.  Instead, I keep getting 10.  Obviously, this isn't right.

My question is, how would I increase the variable `zero` by 10 each time and save that value back to the variable `zero`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript passes by value, so modifying the passed value won't have any effect on the caller's variable. You'd need to use the return value:

```
var zero = 10;

function sum(elem, num) {
    return elem + num;
}

console.log(zero = sum(zero, 10));
console.log(zero = sum(zero, 10));
console.log(zero = sum(zero, 10));
```

Answer (score 4):

When you do

```
elem += num
```

...in your function, you're incrementing the value held by the `elem` argument passed to the function, *not* the variable that argument's value came from. There is no link between the argument `elem` and the variable `zero`, the *value* of `zero`, as of the call to `some`, gets passed into the function.

Answer (score 2):

Primitives like number are passed by value not by reference. It means that you increment the local `elem` variable, not the `zero` ones.
So, you need – outside the function – to reassign `zero` after each call of the function:

```
console.log(zero = some(zero, 10));
```

Or, makes zero a property of an object, an pass the object. Objects are passed by reference, and not value. So, for instance:

```
var zero = [10]

function some(elem, num) {
    return elem[0] += num;
}

console.log(some(zero, 10));
console.log(some(zero, 10));
console.log(some(zero, 10));
```

That's because `zero` nows is not a primitive, but an Array, and arrays are objects and therefore passed by reference.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sum = (function sum(num){
    var zero = 0;
    return function () {
        return zero += num;
    };

})(10);

console.log(sum());
console.log(sum());
console.log(sum());
```

Answer (score 0):

`zero = some(zero, 10)`

You return the new value in some(). So you have to assign it to zero after the function call.